# Getter and Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, reference, tabs, segmentation-fault, getter

I need a bit of help on my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;


class Position {
public :
    int             line;
    int             column;

                    Position(int,int);
                    Position();
};
Position::Position(int n, int m) : line{n},column{m}{}

class Board {
private :
    int**           tab;
    int             nbline;
    int             nbcolumn;

public  :
                    Board(int, int);
    void            setValue(Position&, int);
    int             getValue(Position&);
    int             getNbline();
    int             getNbcolumn();
};


class Play {
private :
 // Play         m_instance;
    void            moves(Board, Position&); // quand le joueur joue
 // void            moves(Board, Position); // quand l'IA joue. Mettre une énum pour direction,
    bool            wincondition(Board);
    Play&           operator=(const Play&);

public :
// static Play&    Instance();

};

Board::Board(int m, int n) : tab{new int*[m]}, nbline{m}, nbcolumn{n}{

   int  x(0);
   for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        tab[i] = new int[n];

        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            tab[i][j] = x; x++;}}
}


void     Board::setValue(Position& p, int value)         { tab[p.line][p.column] = value; }
int      Board::getValue(Position& p)                    { return tab[p.line][p.column];  }
int      Board::getNbline()                              { return nbline;                 }
int      Board::getNbcolumn()                            { return nbcolumn;               }



void Play::moves(Board tab, Position& blank) {
   /* int             c = getch() ;
    Position        tmp;

    if(c==0 || c==224) {c = getch();


    switch(c){
    case 75 : //left
        if(blank.column-1>=0) {
                tmp.column = blank.column;
                tmp.line   = blank.line;

                tab.setValue(blank,tab.getValue(tmp));
                blank.column++;
                tab.setValue(blank, 0);
                }
        break;

    case 72 : // haut
        if(blank.line+1<=0) {
                tmp.column = blank.column+1;
                tmp.line   = blank.line;

                tab.setValue(blank,tab.getValue(tmp));
                blank.column++;
                tab.setValue(blank, 0);
            }
        break;


    case 77 ://droit
        if(blank.column+1<=tab.getNbcolumn()) {
                tmp.column = blank.column;
                tmp.line   = blank.line;

                tab.setValue(blank,tab.getValue(tmp));
                blank.column--;
                tab.setValue(blank, 0);
            }
        break;

    case 80 : //bas
        if(blank.line+1<=tab.getNbline()) {
                tmp.column = blank.column+1;
                tmp.line   = blank.line;

                tab.setValue(blank,tab.getValue(tmp));
                blank.column++;
                tab.setValue(blank, 0);
            }
        break;
    default : cout << "\n ERROR " << endl; break; // erreur
    }
}*/
}

int main()
{
    int             lines, columns;


    cout << "Enter number of lines" << endl;
    cin >> lines;
    cout << "Enter number of columns" << endl;
    cin >> columns;

    Board           tab(lines,columns);
    Position        pos(lines,columns);
    Position&       p = pos;


    for (int i = 0; i<lines;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<columns;j++)
        {
            cout << tab.getValue(p) << " ";
            if (i == lines) { cout << endl;}
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I call `getValue` at line 139, I get a segmentation fault. Get value is defined at line 57. When executing `getValue`, both `p.line` and `p.column` got the right values caught at the beginning of main function.

The program got no errors, only 2 warnings because I don't use `Play::moves` arguments (because currently between `/* */`, waiting for tests). I use Code::Blocks with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11`.

I really see no reason for a segmentation fault. Did I miss something?

Comment: *I need, not i'm need... :(

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: If your description includes “in line 139,” your code is probably way too long for this format. Starting with the fact that your code listing includes a long block that is commented out. As LRiO said: Use the debugger to check you variables. If that doesn't help, start removing everything not relevant to the error. You'll probably find where you made a mistake. If you do not and have reduced the code to, say, ten lines or so that are easy to read, you'll have a much better chance of someone reading the code and looking for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling get with a position that is set to the size of your board.  Since arrays are 0 index based the size of your array is actually one past the end of the array.

```
const int size = 100
int arr[size];  //0, 1, 2, ... 98, 99
arr[size];  // fail arr is 0-99 and size is 100
```